# Which properties should be declared in View controller m and which in model m objective c?

Tags: ios

Sorry for noob question. I have of bunch of properties for my iPhone app and first three properties are straight forward like this

**model.m file**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *celsiusStack;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *fahrenheitStack;
```

**viewController.m**

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userFinishedTyping;
```

Now what should I do if property is ambiguous and is used extensively in both model and viewController. Does it matter where I declare it and what is a good practice.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL celsius;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on the purpose of celcius?

One of the basic concepts of the MVC pattern is to make it easier to replace the GUI completely without the need to modify the underlying model.

My guess is that it would make good sense to have the celcius property in your model, but again. It depends on it's purpose.

Comment: In this case its setting the degrees to be either displayed in Celsius or Fahrenheit

Comment: Thought so. I would place it in your model. I would then have a method on the model called getTemperature, and let the model decide if the temperature returned should be celcius or fahrenheit